# if I use a BlankApp(xaml) Template in Metro Apps and develop my desired UI , will it work accordingly in Windows phone also?

Tags: windows-phone-7, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

1) What I have understood that if you develop a application in metro style, it work in desktop, tablet and also phone?

2) I can understand if I use a standard template like grid template for developing my metro style app, that grid view will be converted to listview because of visual state transitions and will work in Windows phone. but my doubt is if we use a blank app template and develop whatever UI I developed  as per client requirement will it be able to render or  show up in windows phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A WinRT app (I assume that is what you mean by Metro) will run on the desktop/tablet and theoretically a Windows Phone 8 device without code changes.  First, note that we are talking about Windows Phone 8 (not the current Windows Phone 7) and that it runs, not that the UI layout will be exactly right.
2. You can design the app however you like, whether it conforms to the Metro design or some other look altogether.  If it is developed on WinRT, it should be code compatible with the phone as well.